# sqlite pattern matching in c

Tags: sqlite, pattern-matching

The following query i have tried, is working fine while running in sqlite manager using the database, But while i try to execute the same in my C program the query is not being executed.

```
Query: "SELECT * FROM Object WHERE Path like ? "
```

Order of query execution:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2
sprintf(buf,"'/%d -%%%%'",objNum); (buf= '/x -%%')
sqlite3_bind_text
sqlite3_step
```

An example row in the table(object)

```
Path                  artist        album       genre
/0 - xxxx.mp3         xxxxx        yyyyy        zzzzz
/1 - aaaa.mp3         wwwww        yyyyy        qqqqq
```

I have to use the number in the start of the path to get the rest of the details in the table. any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: The number surely isn't `x` (what is the actual value?), and you don't need two `%`.

Comment: I have added x as a placeholder for a integer, and the % were just what I have tried.. Which didn't work for me :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use single quotes for parameters strings; all data in parameters is taken directly without any changes.
Use:

```c
sprintf(buf, "/%d -%%", objNum);
```